# Google Analytics Reporting SDK for iPhone?

Tags: ios, sdk, report, adsense

Upon exploring new ideas for apps, I stumbled on one that seemed pretty easy to do once nailed down to the right SDK, etc. I want to use Google OAuth authentication system to report Google Analytics data into my app, from the users account.

A couple days of researched turned up pretty much nothing but on how to add Google ANalytics to YOUR app to track YOUR views, etc.

Where should I begin? Does Google have Sample Code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Google has a complete API for accessing the Google Analytics data.  See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/

There are several iOS apps out there that already use this data to provide graphical and numerical data on your GA account.

Comment: So would I look into the Core Reporting API?

Comment: Also, are there any specifics for iOS? In the tutorials and documentation, I just see Java, Python, etc. But no iOS Objective C.

Comment: Yes, anything you get out of the normal web-based reports you can access with the Core Reporting API.

Comment: Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/ for Objective-C code.

Comment: Okay, great. Are there any specifics for iOS? Like I mentioned before, only seeing Python, Java, etc.

Comment: Still confused. There is no sample code for Analytics. And where do I download the API files?

Comment: Analytics code: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSource%2FServices%2FAnalytics%2FGenerated

Comment: Okay, thank you, and sorry for all the questions. Now that I have got the source, because there is no example project to show me how to use the source. Are there any good tutorials for GTLAnalytics?